# How severe are the interestingly disclosed AMD flaws?

Tags: hardware

CTS disclosed several "flaws" in the AMD Ryzen architecture chips. These flaws are called Ryzenfall, Masterkey, Fallout and Chimera (https://amdflaws.com/). However several technology sites (for example [Wired](https://www.wired.com/story/amd-backdoor-cts-labs-backlash/)) and blogs raised questions as to the motives, release style and severity of the flaws. There also seems to be a very odd disclaimer on the CTS sites. So far it has been hard to find any data without a lot of hype. How severe are these flaws and what do I need to do to secure my systems?

Comment: Probably published by short-sellers. See https://www.servethehome.com/bizarre-amd-epyc-ryzen-vulnerability-disclosure/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quotes from the rather detail-free [whitepaper](https://safefirmware.com/amdflaws_whitepaper.pdf):

> Exploiting MASTERKEY requires an attacker to be able to re-flash the BIOS with a specially crafted BIOS update.

Exploitable only if you've got the BIOS manufacturer's signing key (if they use one), have written a custom BIOS for the computer being targeted, and (generally) have physical access to the machine.

> Exploitation [of RYZENFALL] requires that an attacker be able to run a program with local-machine elevated administrator privileges. Accessing the Secure Processor is done through a vendor supplied driver that is digitally signed.
>
> Exploitation [of FALLOUT] requires that an attacker be able to run a program with local-machine elevated administrator privileges. Accessing the Secure Processor is done through a vendor supplied driver that is digitally signed.
>
> Prerequisites for Exploitation [of CHIMERA]: A program running with local-machine elevated administrator privileges. Access to the device is provided
> by a driver that is digitally signed by the vendor.

So, at a minimum, you already need full control of the computer and a third party's signing key to exploit these vulnerabilities.  Might be useful for a state-level actor trying to install an undetectable keylogger or the like, but the average person isn't at increased risk because of them.

Comment: All these bugs make me think of https://xkcd.com/1957/